Setting Up JWT with Ktor
I’m trying to setup ktor to use JWT but my authentication server (Duende Identity Server) doesn’t have a jwks.json endpoint, instead it uses .“well-known/openid-configuration/jwks”
In the JWT verifier if I specify a string as the issuer then it appends “.well-known/jwks.json” and obviously that doesn’t work
I think the underlying Auth0 libraries allow us to specify a URL for the JWKS endpoint address but I can’t see a similar override for the verifier. There is an override that takes a JWTVerifier but to create one of these I need an Algorithm.RSA256, to create that I need a public key and to get the public key I need a token (I think)
Is there a way to get what I want?

You can create an instance of the JwkProvider by using the UrlJwkProvider constructor, which has the URL parameter. For example: UrlJwkProvider(URL("https://example.com/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks"))
